# Why does my input function doesn't get input correctly?

Tags: c, string, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm new to C. I asked this question before, I knew an error in my code, but still, it is not working.
I want to take input from the user and store it in allocated memory. ptrsptr and patientsnum are global variables. ptrsptr points to another allocated memory that stores pointers to patients' data.

```
  char name[51];
  int age=0;
  char agestr[3];
  char infectiondate [11];
  char address[51];
  char *patientptr;
  char **newptr;

  printf("\nEnter the patient name (50 characters at maximum): ");
  scanf ("%50s", name);

  newptr = (char**) realloc(ptrsptr, patientsnum*sizeof(char *));
  if (newptr) ptrsptr = newptr;
  else
  {
    patientsnum --;
    printf ("Not enough memory.\n");
    return;
  }

  patientptr = (char*) calloc (118, sizeof (char)); // allocation after being sure patient doesn't exist
  if (!patientptr)
  {
    patientsnum --;
    printf ("Not enough memory.\n");
    return;
  }

  strcpy(patientptr, name);

  printf("Enter the patient age: ");
  scanf ("%d", &age);
  sprintf (agestr, "%2d", age);
  strcpy((patientptr + 51),agestr);

  printf("Enter the patient date of infection (in form of dd/mm/year): ");
  scanf ("%10d", infectiondate);
  strcpy((patientptr + 54),infectiondate);

  printf("Enter the patient address (50 characters at maximum): ");
  scanf ("%50s", address);
  strcpy((patientptr + 65),address);

  *(ptrsptr+patientsnum-1) = patientptr;

  printf ("\nPatient added succesfully.\n");
}
```

The output is:

```
Enter the patient name (50 characters at maximum): John
Enter the patient age: 20
Enter the patient date of infection (in form of dd/mm/year): 20/10/2019
Enter the patient address (50 characters at maximum):
Patient added succesfully.
```

I can't input the address. What is wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: You ignore the return value of `scanf()`at your own risk.

Comment: Using scanf is tricky. You probably have a "return" waiting in the input, from the last number, which kills your address. http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: Suggestion: always **use `fgets()` for user input**.

Comment: Suggestion: set the warning level of your compiler as high as it will go, and **mind the warnings**!!

Comment: You don't include the declaration of `ptrsptr`, and it probably is uninitialized, giving you a coredump.  As you have been hinted, pleas read [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question to supply what it lacks.

Comment: You have too many errors in your code, to accept that just correcting them you have not deleted more, when you posted only a snippet.  Post complete code... please!

Comment: @LuisColorado I posted the answer. I got it from a comment here. Everything works fine now. I hope there are no more ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks I am still a beginner that doesn't know much about `scanf`. But, it looks the error was putting some integer into char string.